# What do the words ""swoops in to keep her in the middle of the act" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the words "swoops in to keep her in the middle of the action" in the following sentence (not available online) from the description of the game Gravity Rider Zero:

> Whether the player is climbing hills or hugging curves, a smart camera
> **swoops in to keep her in the middle of the action.**

Here is a description of the game from Google Play:

> In this bike balancing game, you will be climbing over obstacles,
> discovering new clever mechanics and trials to overcome in each level.
>
> Giant ramps, lasers, spikes, or good old gravity will try to get in
> your way. No sweat though, your vehicle has the perfect speed to pass
> through - with a bit of finesse, you will be fine and not fall off.

Comment: to swoop means: to come down towards.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that *her* refers to the player.

So however the action of the game moves around in three-dimensional space, the "camera" moves to keep the player in the middle of it.